# Stuttering playback of certain .mp4's

Tags: video, omxplayer

This is actually a follow-up, same situation, but different problem from : 
[Playing WMV with codec on OMXplayer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39518/playing-wmv-with-codec-on-omxplayer)

I have Raspbian Jessie with the Adafruit Video Looper installed. It uses a special implementation of OMXPlayer that helps with shorter looptimes. So I can't say I'm using the latest OMXPlayer. (Thought 40-something commits behind master) Also using a class 10 card.

The issue I have is that with a certain MP4 file, whenever I start playing it, it stutters in the first 10 seconds, and then plays fine for the next 4 minutes (the full length of the file), then loops and at the start it stutters again. Since this is used as a Mediaplayer for displays on expo's, it's not really pretty.

The weird part is, the original video, which is a lot bigger, plays fine. Both are .mp4 files

```
Zhe numbers:
Stuttering video:
1920*1080
Bitrate: 2669kbps
Frames: 25fps

Works fine:
1920*1080
Bitrate: 19492kbps
Frames: 29fps
```

Is there any way that I can check on what's the bottleneck or why it does what it does? The issue is 'solved' in this case by using another video, but it should be as versatile as possible, or I should at least have to know what causes it.. Since the bitrate is clearly not the issue here..

I tried with outputting the stats while playing, but I don't even understand half of it..

EDIT: The idea of the videolooper is to play the files from a USB-stick, but tried both. From the stick, from the sd, with the videolooper starting on boot, omxplayer from commandline,...

EDIT2: GPU Split is 512/512, but behaves the same as in the default case

Answer (score 1):

Found this out by accident:

Reinstalled the omxplayer for a reason I do not remember (and now using the official omxplayer, not the Adafruit version) and the stutter is just gone.

I did (after hours and hours of reading) learn tho that a lower bitrate for the same movie usually means worse playback since it's compressed more. That might be the issue here, higher compression and more problems with playing it. I always assumed that the higher the bitrate, the more the pi would suffer. It seems to be the other way around.

Comment: Higher compression could certainly result in worse playback performance, but lower frame rate definitely shouldn't. If anything a lower frame rate should mean less content and less required compression.

Comment: I meant bit rate of course.. Never changed the framerate..